# Python: How can i import a script from another folder that also locally imports other scripts with relative paths/local text files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have been given a python program that runs on its own. The structure is such that there one .py file (lets call it **app.py**) that imports many other scripts from its nearby folders and uses them t do something. Those other modules have local config.txt files and also import other local modules.

I would like to have my own script somewhere else that imports this "app.py" and just call a function from it. The problem is: This function i would like to call depends on other modules that are relatively imported to app.py itself and when i try to import app.py to my script, is tells me that i cant find the relative imports that app.py has.

I have done quite some digging (with adding **__init.py__** files, using system.path.append / insert stuff i am quite familiar by now ) and i found that when i try to run my script it becomes the current working directory and any relative directory imported from app.py - which is imported by my script- can not be found since it is simple not there.

What i can do i, i can import everything with their absolute paths or add every package/folder to the system path but since there more than 10 packages, i dont want to do that. It also would be really problematic if i move the app.py and modules surrounding it.

The app.py is very self contained and can be put anywhere. I will appreciate any kind of advice to solve this problem in a nice/elegant way.

**TL;DR** : I have a script that tries to import another script in another directory but it also imports other scripts with relative paths. The script i try to import gets imported but cant import other scripts it normally imports.

Answer (score 0):

One variant would be to specify the directory where `app.py` resides in the `PYTHONPATH`.

Let's assume you have the following files:

***yourscript.py*** -> which can be anywhere on the syste,

```
import app
app.dosomething()
```

***somepackage/app.py***

```
import somemod
from subpack import innermod

def dosomething():
    somemod.x()
    othermod.y()
```

***somepackage/somemod.py***

```
def x():
    print("XXX")
```

***somepackage/subpack/innermod.py***

```
def y():
    print("YYYY")
```

Now if you would call `yourscript` like:

`PYTHONPATH=<path_to_your_somepackage> python yourscript.py`

It will resolve the dependencies in yourscript relative to that `PYTHONPATH` which is the path where `somepackage` resides.